# Check if queryset already exists

Tags: python, django, duplicates

I have a list of querysets such as `([qSet1, qSet2, qSet3],[qSet3, qSet2],[qSet1, qSet3])`

Then, I want to add another queryset, but only if it not already exists in list. Sets can have the same content, but in different order: `[qSet1, qSet2], [qSet2, qSet1]`. That querysets must be considered as the same => must not to be added twice.

How can I do this?

Comment: If `qSet1` is a set then it looks like you have a tuple of lists of sets.

Comment: @AlexHall all qSets are Querysets from django filter function

Comment: So correct the description of your question then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check for sameness for a set of QuerySets (*pun intended*), you can make use of the underlying SQL query gotten from the `.query` method which Django provides for QuerySets. This method returns a string literal.

Say you have a list of tuples of QuerySets:

```
list_of_querysets = [(qSet1, qSet2, qSet3), (qSet3, qSet2), (qSet1, qSet3)]
```

To check if a new arbitrary tuple `qsets_arb = (qSet_arb1, qSet_arb2)` already has a match in the list, you would do:

```
def get_sql(tuple_of_querysets):
    '''Return a set of SQL statements from a tuple of QuerySets'''
    return set([str(queryset.query) for queryset in tuple_of_querysets])

# ordering of items in sets do not matter: set([q1, q2]) = set([q2, q1])
if get_sql(qsets_arb) in map(get_sql, list_of_querysets[:]):
     print("This tuple of QuerySets has already been included")
else:
     list_of_querysets.append(qsets_arb)
```

That should pretty much do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to compare is the content of the lists, and you do not want order to make a difference, you should use a `set`:

```
set([qSet1, qSet2]) == set([qSet2, qSet1])
```

This is assuming that the same queryset is not twice in the same list.